# Managing rails app environments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui-autocomplete

i have a rails app with the three default environments. Everything works fine until I added a new environment. I added it by copying out the production env file. The problems which this led to:
i) I was using jqueryui autocomplete(was working fine before) which failed to load when i tried  (rails s -e staging). So i went ahead to precompile assets using rake. Then the assets(images) also stopped loading (Error : no route matches ).I tried running the server in default(dev) mode and lo and behold the images were loading but nw the jqui autocomplete also started bugging here.
ii) I mentioned fb app settings in facebook.yml for staging(my new env), but it still points to the app constants set for the development mode.

ANY HELP would be highly appreciated. I'm stuck with this for 2-3 days now.

Comment: Did it works in production?

Comment: i cant push it to production as it might affect the live site..

Comment: `rails s -e production` in your local machine.

Comment: Ok..so i reset my codebase to the last point where it was working. now everything works fine in dev mode, but in production mode jqueryui autcomplete does not work. (I didn set up staging yet)